# Difference between On Delete Cascade & On Update Cascade in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables in MySQL database- `parent`, `child`. I'm trying to add foreign key references to my child table based on the parent table. Is there any significant difference between `ON UPDATE CASCADE` and `ON DELETE RESTRICT`

My Parent Table

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

My Question is: What is the difference between the following sql queries.

1)

```
CREATE TABLE child (
    id INT, 
    parent_id INT,
    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) 
        REFERENCES parent(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

2)

```
CREATE TABLE child (
    id INT, 
    parent_id INT,
    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) 
        REFERENCES parent(id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

And are there any errors in the following query??

3)

```
 CREATE TABLE child (
        id INT, 
        parent_id INT,
        INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
        FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) 
            REFERENCES parent(id)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

What does these queries (1,2 & 3) mean?? Are they same???

Gracias.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**`on delete cascade`**

> It will delete all the child records when parent record is deleted, so
>   that there will be no child record when parent is deleted.

**`on update cascade`**

> It will update the child records parent_id when parent record id that
>   change. In rare case we use on update cascade
>
> eg:- suppose your parent id is 4 digit and due to expansion later on
>   you need change it to 10 digit. In that case, ON UPDATE CASCADE would
>   allow you to change the primary key value and any tables that have
>   foreign key references to the value will be changed accordingly.